# Pass Item ID to webpart

Tags: web-part, custom-list, sharepoint-addin

We are creating a ClientWebPart that we want to be present on the Default Display Form for items on a custom list view that's part of our application.

I can't work out how to pass the Id of the selected ListItem to the WebPart so that it can adjust it's behaviour. I'm assuming it can be passed with the URL to the WebPart.

I've considered using properties on the WebPart but they seem to be hard coded when the WebPart is placed on the form.

The built in controls seem to allow this. We can display a list of related ListItems to this ListItem. That seems to use something called "Connections" which I've been unable to re-create.

Comment: This walkthrough might help on creating connected webparts... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi @BlueBird, the only problem is that's for 2010 and doesn't fit in with SharePoint 2013's new App Model

Comment: @MatthewSteeples, Can you use [SharePoint 2010: Get Selected Items from List View in Visual Web Part](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/sharepoint-2010-get-selected-items-from-list-view-in-visual-web-part/).. I am not sure if it will work with SharePoint 2013's App Model